# Sorting continuous form in Access Runtime

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a client that doesn't actually have Access, so they use the Access Runtime 2016 to use my program. In the runtime version there is no ribbon, but mostly they manage without.

There is only one issue, there is a continuous form that the user needs to be able to sort ascending or descending. In the full version of Access, there's a convenient little button to take care of that.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574642), but it doesn't work when I try it. I'm assuming that it's because my client is using Runtime 2016. There is also [a question that addresses this for Access 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110541), but there's no way (as far as I know) to make buttons for Access 2007 runtime and later.

What is the recommended method to provide sorting (and filtering) for Access 2016 runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I never let my customers use the Access UI for sorting or anything else, I bind the double click event of the header in any sortable column to code that uses the `OrderBy` and `OrderByOn` properties of the form to set the sorting up using VBA.

Here is sample code:

```
Private Sub s_Description_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

If Me.OrderBy = "Description" Then
    Me.OrderBy = "Description DESC"
  Else
    Me.OrderBy = "Description"
  End If
Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when Access already provides sorting?

Comment: Because I create applications for users that do not know how to use Access and by locking them out of the Access UI I protect them from themselves. It also allows me to manage what types of sorting are allowed/make sense instead of the way Access does it. And it only takes a couple of minutes when you know how to do it.

Comment: I added sample code above that can flip between Ascending and Descending sort on Double-Click. Just bind code like that on the double click event of every column you want to allow soring by.

Comment: I'm still a bit bothered doing this for my client, whose technically-oriented secretary would be perfectly capable of using Access' built-in features without messing up anything, but it doesn't seem like the Runtime version has those built-in features, and this works beautifully, so I am marking this the answer. I hope that they don't start asking for filters, too...